# what does $(\Omega^T,\mathcal{A}^T)$ mean?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega_t,\mathcal{A}_t), t\in T$ be a collection of measurable spaces. What does the notation mean? $(\Omega^T,\mathcal{A}^T)$

Comment: Most likely the Cartesian product $\Omega^T=\prod_{t\in T}\Omega_t$ equipped with the [product measure](http://planetmath.org/infiniteproductmeasure).

Comment: so $\mathcal{A}^T$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega^T$?

Comment: Yes, see the link in my comment above. The $\sigma$ algebra generated by the ad hoc products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Omega^T\triangleq \{ (\omega_t)_{t\in T} : \omega_t\in\Omega_t\}$ is the set of all configurations $\omega\triangleq  (\omega_t)_{t\in T}$.

- If $T$ is finite say $T = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ then $\Omega^T=\Omega^{\{1, \ldots, n\}}=\Omega_1\times\ldots\times\Omega_n$ is the set of all the n-tuples $(\omega_t)_{t\in \{1,\ldots,n\}}=(\omega_1,\ldots\omega_n)$.
- If $T$ is the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers then $\Omega^T=\Omega^{\mathbb{N}}=\Omega_1\times\ldots\times\Omega_n\times\ldots\quad $ is the set of all infinite sequences $(\omega_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}=(\omega_1,\ldots\omega_n,\ldots \;)$.
- If T is the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers then $\Omega^T=\Omega^{\mathbb{R}}$ is the set of all applications $T=\mathbb{R}\ni t\mapsto \omega_t\in\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\Omega_t$.
- Generally, if $T$ is any arbitrary set then the configurations $(\omega_t)_{t\in T}$ are nothing more than functions of $T$ to $\bigcup_{t\in T}\Omega_t$.

Most times the sigma field $\mathcal{A}^T$ is the sigma field of cylinders. You can find a beautiful exposition of the sigma of the cylinders in the book of [Robert Ash](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GkqQoRpCO2QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Robert%20Ash&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ei=-0hkUYzEFOOh0AHG7ICwDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Robert%20Ash&f=false).